# Show Alert Icon if Data exists in DB - JQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table where I need to check data if they already exist in the database. If they do, an alert icon should appear beside the trash icon under Action column on their respective rows and show the appropriate info regarding them.

Currently, I was able to return the ajax data I need if the data I'm comparing already exists in the database. But I don't how I'll show the icons on their respective rows.

[image]

Here's my returned data:

```
{"receive_array":[{"id":"77","batch_id":"45","courier_name":"","vendor_name":"","status":"stored","batch_no":"9","courier_tracking_no":"123"},"",{"id":"126","batch_id":"65","courier_name":"QW12","vendor_name":"Amazon","status":"itemized","batch_no":"18","courier_tracking_no":"QW11"}]}
```

Here's my Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: window.base_url+'oss/admin/check_receive_data', 
        data: $.param($('form#receiving-form').serializeArray()),
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success: function (response) {
            //THIS IS WHERE THE  PROCESS SHOULD TAKE PLACE
            $.each(response.receive_array, function(index, val) {
            });  
        },
            error: function (MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("There was an error: " + errorThrown);  
        }
    });
```

**EDIT:**

HTML:

```
<table id="receiving-box-table" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Courier Tracking #</th>
            <th>Courier</th>
            <th>Vendor</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" form="receiving-form" class="form-control input-sm track_no" name="courier_tracking_no[]" id="courier_tracking_no_1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" form="receiving-form" class="form-control input-sm" name="courier_name[]" id="courier_name_1" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {return false;}"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" form="receiving-form" class="form-control input-sm" name="vendor_name[]" id="vendor_name_1" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {return false;}"/></td>
            <td class="box-action"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs clear-data" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Clear input fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

(The rows aside from the first row are dynamically created.)

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!
-Eli

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know how to show an icon or that you don't now how to match the values in json to the values in the rows?

Comment: paste your html here

Comment: @Difster I don't know how to show the icon on the same row where the values match.

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR see the updated code. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming that id is unique for each row of the table, you need to create an array of the table id fields and then loop over the json and with each loop look for a match in the other array. If so, then find add the icon. Maybe have You'll just have to find the child elements of each row. Or maybe give the cells with the trash icon their own unique id also that corresponds with the main id of that row. `trash + id` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are required 2 loops 1 for the data to be matched and other is the response you got from DB like,

```
....
    success: function (response) {
        // Change selectors as per you HTML design
        $('table tr').each(function(index){ 
            var ctno=$(this).find('td:first input').val(); // get courier trancking

            // check if ctno is present in response array or not
            var arr = jQuery.grep(response.receive_array, function( n ) {
               return ( n.courier_tracking_no === ctno);
            });
            if(arr.length){ // if present then show error message
               $('span.exists').show(); // let it be hidden by default
            }
        });

    },
....
```

Comment: I tried using 3 data with only 2 duplicates but all the icons still show. https://snag.gy/jJ4SqE.jpg

Comment: I added an ID per button to call them specifically since calling the class means calling everything that has the same class. I was just wondering... I tried to alert the data value but when I entered only 1 data, the alert shows twice. The first one is undefined and the second one is the actual data.

Comment: You can find your error icon in `tr` like `if(arr.length){ $(this).find('span.exists').show();}. Also in success callback first hide all exists buttons so that only the existing once can be shown.

Comment: How do I know if there are no duplicate data at all?

Comment: You can create a flag variable before both loops, and if the flag is not changed then it means there are no duplicates

Comment: Why did I not think of that? Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Sometime, it happens. :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150705/discussion-between-jeepers-creepers-and-rohan-kumar).